# Implement Datatables TableTools to export whole data to excel including the filters

Tags: mysql, excel, datatables, tabletools

I'm using PHP and jQuery DataTables Tabletools with server-side pagination. I want to implement TableTools export buttons to export whole data including filters applied.

When `xls` in TableTools is enabled then it allows to export the data in **current page only**. Is there any method to fetch all data in MySQL and export to XLS as CSV?

**Next Problem:**

While exporting the long numeric data, for example `2081420150000001` the data is converted to exponential format i.e. `2.0814E+15` when viewed in Excel. What code in TableTools is required to leave the data as such?

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off writing a query from Excel to the MySQL source. Why go via HTML with jQuery to get data from MySQL to Excel.

Comment: My question was incomplete. I'm using PHP and jQuery DataTables Tabletools for Server-side pagination. I want to implement TableTools export buttons to export whole data including filters applied.

Comment: The tabletools export should export all pages, not just the current page. Without seeing your code, there's no way to tell why this might be happening. Please post your code to show how you're using tabletools. As for the Excel issue, this is an Excel issue, not a TableTools issue. By default, Excel will display numbers like this. Just change the column format (Format --> Cells) and select Number. This will fix the Excel display issue.